# Gateway and JHipster UAA should connect with Jhipster-register?

Tags: jhipster

I have some questions regarding the creation of Microservice gateway and Jhipster UAA.

When I generate the gateway connects with Jhipster-register and when I generate the JHipster UAA too?

In other words: Both should connect with Jhipster-register?

The image of the architecture diagram found in this Jhipster documentation creates the doubt: [Using JHipster UAA for Microservice Security - **Architecture diagram**](https://www.jhipster.tech/using-uaa/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all services including the gateway, UAA, and any microservices will connect to JHipster Registry.  This allows the services to fetch the necessary information from the UAA to authenticate users and validate JWT tokens (passed via cookies).